# is Queue.Count thread safe?

Tags: c#

I need one thread to modify Queue (both adding and removing elements) and another thread only to call `Queue.Count`. Would it be safe or I need to use `locks` or `ConcurrentQueue`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Queue property is *not* thread-safe, as per the docs.

But it is an atomic int, the worst that could happen is that you read the wrong (outdated) value. Which may or may not be a problem.

But since you'll have to do something to prevent your reading thread from caching the value you might as well `lock()`.

Comment: reading outdated value is fine for me, but may I read wrong value? i.e. half of `int` is changed and another half is not changed

Comment: The word _atomic_ answers that : No.  But theoretically the Queue could set it to some weird value during an Enqueue or Dequeue, so it's still not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

`Queue` does not provide thread safety guarantees, so yes you do need one of the two alternatives you mention.

> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread
>   safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
>
> A Queue(Of T) can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the
>   collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a collection
>   is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. To guarantee thread
>   safety during enumeration, you can lock the collection during the
>   entire enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple
>   threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own
>   synchronization.

Comment: I think I will use "extra int" better then. i.e. on one thread I will write `int count = queue.Count` each time element is added or removed from queue and from another thread I will take `count`. btw would be that thread-safe? :)

Comment: @javapowered: Of course it would *not* be safe, nothing has changed. You still have a race condition on `count`.

Comment: But what can go wrong? Will I receive some kind of exception? Unexpected value?

Comment: I don't see how that would be any different.  Now your "count" int isn't thread-safe unless you lock around *it*.

Comment: @Joe I don't access `Queue` methods from different threads I access `int`. I can also declare `int` as `volatile`

Comment: @javapowered: Google "race condition".

Comment: my example is extremely simple. one thread writes to `volatile int` and another thread reads `volatile int`. if this will not work then how exactly that will not work?

Comment: @javapowered: As I said, race condition. This is the most basic concurrency stuff we 're talking about, there are thousands of tutorials on the internet. The general idea is that since you are setting `count` and modifying the queue without any locks, there's a very good chance that `count` will not reflect the actual contents of the queue.

Comment: @Joe it should work even without `volatile` as I understand. maximum that I will get - not latest value. this is ok for me....

Answer (score 3):

It's not guaranteed to be threadsafe.

The current implementation of `Count` is threadsafe. It's not likely to change, but there's no promise.

Most of the time, this isn't very useful though. If you were doing something like outputting a current estimate of the size to UI, then that's perfectly safe. If you make any decision on the basis of it, that is not safe:

```
if(queue.Count != 0)
  return queue.Dequeue; //not thread-safe as Dequeue isn't threadsafe.

if(queue.Count != 0)
{
  lock(queue)
    return queue.Dequeue; //not thread-safe, won't corrput
                          //queue but may error as Count could now be zero.
}
lock(queue)
  if(queue.Count != 0)
    return queue.Dequeue; //thread-safe

ConcurrentQueue<int> cQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
/*...*/
int val;
if(cQueue.TryDequeue(out val))
  return val; //perfectly thread-safe and lock-free,
              //but more expensive than single-threaded use of Queue<int>
```

Comment: i only need to get queue size to display it in UI to the user in information purpose. I just hope that this will not result in any errors/exceptions etc

Comment: Not with the current implementation, but there's no absolute promise a service pack or security update won't change that.

Answer (score 0):

From the Queue [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx) under the **Thread Safety** heading:

> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread
>   safe. **Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.**
>
> To guarantee the thread safety of the Queue, all operations must be
>   done through the wrapper returned by the Synchronized method.
>
> Enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe
>   procedure. Even when a collection is synchronized, other threads can
>   still modify the collection, which causes the enumerator to throw an
>   exception. To guarantee thread safety during enumeration, you can
>   either lock the collection during the entire enumeration or catch the
>   exceptions resulting from changes made by other threads.

msdn has pretty good documentation. I advise you to look there the next time.